# Suitcase check-in online

Tags: luggage, bookings

We booked United ticket from Detroit to Newark. We couldn’t book suitcase transport online. How can I book transportation for a bag larger than cabin size?

Comment: How did you book? Through the United website or through another site? What is the fare? Some fares already include one piece of checked luggage, while others don't.

Comment: You can add bags online at United.com anytime. Goto "My Trips" "manage trip" "prepay & save"